# Como trocar a cor do ícone no Materialize?

Tags: css, materialize

Estou usando o framework [materialize](http://materializecss.com) e para se colocar um ícone faço desta maneira:

```html
<i class="material-icons">menu</i>
```

Acontece que por padrão o ícone está na cor branca, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para trocar a cor do ícone?

Já tentei desta forma:

```html
<i class="material-icons black">menu</i>
```

Mas daí fica tudo preto ao redor do ícone, e não é isso que quero, quero mudar somente a cor do ícone.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podes usar algo como: `<i class="material-icons" style="color:#000;">menu</i>`

Ou se quiseres mudar a cor do icon utilizando uma `class` como no exemplo que mencionas-te na pergunta, podes criar uma class especial para isso, como por exemplo:

```css
/* Estas classes abaixo e outras que quiseres adicionar, serão implementadas no teu ficheiro .css */
.blackIcon {color:#000;}
.greenIcon {color:green;}
.rBlueIcon {color:royalblue;}
```

```html
<!-- Este será o teu código HTML -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
    <i class="material-icons rBlueIcon">language</i>
    <i class="material-icons greenIcon">perm_media</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pergunta antiga mais...
O corpo do icone responde à cor do texto:

```
    <i class="material-icons black-text">menu</i>
```